# SWT text field for date

Tags: java, swt

I am using regular SWT text field to represent a date.

The issue is that I am having default value for this filed, but then I add a listener to popup a SWT CALENDAR for selection the new date.

It's working fine, but is there an option to make the field non editable by the user and the listener for the CALENDAR still work.

I don't want the user to edit this field manually, just to user the SWT CALENDAR.

Thanks

Comment: From a UX perspective, please don't. Unless you have a really good reason, a lot of users like to type dates because they find it a lot faster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doesn't the following work?

```
final Text text = new Text(parent, SWT.BORDER);
text.setEditable(false);

text.addListener(SWT.MouseUp, new Listener() {

    @Override
    public void handleEvent(Event arg0) {
        System.out.println("Event");
        text.setText("new text");
    }
});
```

Comment: no , because then the listener of the SWT CALENDAR is not working.

Comment: @user1205079 Changed my answer. The event is triggered although the text is not editable.

Comment: That correct but after the user select the date from the CALENDAR it can;t be inserted to the text again.:(

Comment: @user1205079 Why not? Check updated answer. That works for me.

Comment: the issue that the  text.setText("new text") is calling again the listener kind of loop.

Comment: @user1205079 Not in the code I provided. Please share your code in your question and point out the problem.

Comment: ohh it was mistake in my code you are right;) its working for me,is there an option to make the text color in white like regular text even its not editable.

Comment: found it:)
setBackground(Display.getDefault().getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_WHITE));

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer - do not use a textfield, but instead use label with a button.

Otherwise you will have to mess with the listeners

Comment: it;s not working with label, because i need to look like text and like label

Comment: add a non-editable text and a button to set the date. Button will trigger the Caledar widget, text will display a value.